# ts-node and ts-node-dev don't work with `cannot read property of undefined`, and it is probably not circular import

Tags: typescript, ts-node

But `tsc && node -r esm .` and `nodemon -e ts -x 'tsc && node -r esm .'` works OK.

Everything that I locally imported seems to be undefined with `ts-node` and I have tried `madge` and `detect-circular-deps` and they could not find a problem...

Real project -- https://github.com/patarapolw/rep2recall-web/blob/91e6f6a5870dca52010b4e569d4bb81f7c5be78f/package.json#L92 and https://github.com/patarapolw/rep2recall-web/blob/master/src/backend/server.ts

Answer (score 1):

Use [tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) like this:

```
ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/index.ts
```